# How to create rows dynamically using make_table in prawn pdf

Tags: ruby, prawn

Using Prawn, I need to create the rows of a table dynamically. I am working with `make_table` for that purpose. When I try the following way

```
 rows = "[\"val1\"],[\"val2\"]"

 test = make_table([#{rows}])
```

It gives me the following error

```
 syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ']'
```

The problem seems to be, how to pass the arguments to `make_table` which is expecting a two dimensional array. Or, is there another way to create the rows dynamically for a table using Prawn.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Prawn. You simply created a syntax error in Ruby. For some reason you seem to try wrapping everything into strings.

You probably just want something like:

```
rows = [["val1", "val2"], ["val3", "val4"]]
table rows
```

You can create `rows` dynamically as any other array of strings in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

if `val1` and `val2` are data carrying variables, try this, to extract their data and initiate a table

```
rows = [["#{val1}"], ["#{val2}"]]

test = make_table(test)
```

You can later pass the initiated `test` to draw a table like so

```
table([[test], ["Additional fourth row"]])
```